# Use properties to describe classes

Tags: rdf, owl, rdfs

I think it is possible to use properties to describe rdfs classes. However, is it really a good practice in term of semantics.

As an example, consider that we have:

```
:Animal        a          rdfs:Class.
:Lion          a          rdfs:Class.
:Lion   rdfs:subClassOf   :Animal.
```

Now consider that we want to state something about all lions; for example that they have 30 teeth and covered with fur:

```
:countOfTeeth          a      rdf:Property.
:Lion           :countOfTeeth "30"^^xsd:Integer.
:coveredWith           a      rdf:Property.
:Lion           :coveredWith  :fur.
```

Note that I am stating properties describing the class itself, i.e., not its instances.

**Questions**

1. I find nothing syntactically wrong with this. Right?
2. Now semantically: Is that a common practice? What are the implications of such way of modelling?
3. Now how about instances of `:Lion`, will this knowledge be applicable?
4. Any standard W3C resources?

Please note that I am questioing the usage of properties to describe classes in this way; not whether this way of modelling knowledge about lions' teeth and fur is the best.

**EDIT**

I am talking from a vocabulary building perspective. The interpretation is pretty much depending on the application side. Hence, solutions like making `:Lion` a subclass of an anonymous restriction is not quite what I need.

Comment: It's not uncommon and quite often seen in biological and medical domain. So why not. In OWL 2 it would be called punning, i.e. using the same URI for individuals and classes.

Comment: 3) No, it will just hold for the instance `:Lion` not for individuals of the class `:Lion:`. OR at least not by RDFS nor OWL semantics. Making statements about individuals is clearly done by using OWL class expressions and then do `:Lion SubClassOf: :countOfTeeth value 30`, i.e. using a `hasValue` restriction as superclass. But you said you don't want this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions, in order:

1. There is indeed nothing syntactically wrong with this - though depending on your intent it may be *semantically* incorrect (as in: it may not say what you want it to say);
2. It's not uncommon - you will often see this kind of thing in taxonomical models (e.g. in the biological or medical domain, as mentioned in the comments). Of course that doesn't mean it is the right modelling choice in whatever use case *you* have in mind;
3. In RDFS, the fact that the class `:Lion` has a teeth count has no bearing on what properties any *instances* of the class have. There's no inference that will make individual lions have 30 teeth, nor any validations that, when adding a new Lion, they will have the right amount of teeth.

   In OWL, you would typically use a different modelling approach, by introducing a property *restriction* rather than just blatantly asserting a property at the class level. To be honest your caveat baffles me here: this kind of thing *is* vocabulary building.
4. The [OWL 2 Primer](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/) is a good start, particularly the bits about property restrictions and about "punning" ( = allowing re-use of an indentifier as both a class and an individual).